# Problem verifying a self created openssl root, intermediate and end user certificate

Tags: security, openssl

I'm trying to create a self signed root certificate, intermediate and end user certificate, but for some reason I can only validate the intermediate certificate, the complete chain fails.

This are the commands I'm using to create the certificates:

```
mkdir root interm end

# Root CA:
openssl ecparam -out root/privatekey.pem -name prime256v1 -genkey
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key root/privatekey.pem -out root/certificate.pem -sha256

# Intermediate
openssl ecparam -out interm/privatekey.pem -name prime256v1 -genkey
openssl req -new -key interm/privatekey.pem -out interm/request.csr -sha256
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in interm/request.csr -CA root/certificate.pem -CAkey root/privatekey.pem -out interm/certificate.pem -sha256 -CAcreateserial

# End user
openssl ecparam -out end/privatekey.pem -name prime256v1 -genkey
openssl req -new -key end/privatekey.pem -out end/request.csr -sha256
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in end/request.csr -CA interm/certificate.pem -CAkey interm/privatekey.pem -out end/certificate.pem -sha256 -CAcreateserial
```

Now the verification of the intermediate certificate with the root certificate goes well:

```
openssl verify -CAfile root/certificate.pem interm/certificate.pem 
interm/certificate.pem: OK
```

But when I try to verify the end certificate it fails:

```
openssl verify -CAfile root/certificate.pem -untrusted interm/certificate.pem end/certificate.pem
error 24 at 1 depth lookup: invalid CA certificate
error end/certificate.pem: verification failed
```

Am I creating the certificates wrong? I tried adding -verbose but the output remains the same, not sure why it says that the CA certificate is invalid, it self validate ok:

```
openssl verify -CAfile root/certificate.pem root/certificate.pem
root/certificate.pem: OK
```

Comment: I am also having this exact same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is that intermediate certificate must be flagged with CA:TRUE

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in cinterm/certificate.pem

X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
```

In order to get that create a `ca_intermediate.ext` file with the following content

```
[ v3_intermediate_ca ]
# Extensions for a typical intermediate CA (`man x509v3_config`).
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true, pathlen:0
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign
```

and then run

```
openssl x509 -req -extfile ca_intermediate.ext -extensions v3_intermediate_ca -days 365 -in end/request.csr -CA interm/certificate.pem -CAkey interm/privatekey.pem -out end/certificate.pem -sha256 -CAcreateserial
```